# Can't get login to return to site

Tags: php, authentication

I'm trying to get a basic login system to work and can't seem to get it to return to the main site at all after login. The intent is for a page to have information that's available to the public and hidden info that can be seen after login (all login data assigned by me, no registrations or anything like that).

I can get the login popup to connect to the SQL database and login, but it stalls on the redirect from checklogin.php to, well, anywhere else. I'd prefer for it to redirect back to the page they logged in from (which is not a static login page, but any one of over a hundred item listing pages), but I'll settle for going back to the homepage.

checklogin.php code:

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="SITE_MANAGER"; // Mysql username
$password="PASSWORD"; // Mysql password
$db_name="SITE_login"; // Database name
$tbl_name="login"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error() );

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row

if ($count == 1) {  
    session_register("username");
    session_register("password");
    header("Location: http://HOMEPAGE.com");
    exit();}

else {
     echo "Wrong Username or Password"; 
}

?>
```

Login Box code (added to every page, css through an external page normally)

```
     function login(showhide){
        if(showhide == "show"){
            document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
        }else if(showhide == "hide"){
            document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden"; 
        }
      }

    #popupbox{
        margin: 0;
        margin-left: 40%;
        margin-right: 40%;
        margin-top: 50px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        width: 15%;
        height: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        background: #FBFBF0;
        border: solid #000000 2px;
        z-index: 9;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        visibility: hidden;
        text-align:center;
      }

    <div id="popupbox" text-align="center"> 
    <form name="login" action="checklogin.php" method="post">
    <p>Username:</p>
    <p><input name="username" size="14" /></p>
    <p>Password:</p>
    <p><input name="password" type="password" size="14" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></p>
    </form>
    <br />
    <p style="text-align:center"><a href="javascript:login('show');">Login</a></p>
    <p><a href="javascript:login('hide');">Close</a></p> 
    </div>
```

I tried making use of HTTP_REFERER and REDIRECT and quite a few other methods I've found around the internet, but I can't seem to get any of them to work for me.
I'm fairly new to php and javascript, so I'm willing to bet the flaw is there somewhere and I just can't see it. I'm willing to dabble in another script if need be.

So, can anyone help provide a solution or a little direction?

I'm working with Dreamweaver CS5.5 and HostMonster's cPanel.

Comment: *but it stalls on the redirect from checklogin.php to, well, anywhere else* - where does it redirect to exactly instead of redirecting to where you want it to redirect to? Also i think your question is quite bloatet. The only interesting part is in your checklogin.php. I also can't see how it is relevant that you are using Dreamweaver as an editor.

Comment: How do you know that is where it stalls, can you put a `var_dump($count);` right before your last conditional to see what it outputs?

Comment: Also, do not use `mysql_*` it is [deprecated as of 5.5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php#migration55.deprecated.mysql). Please use [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Instead of `header("Location: http://HOMEPAGE.com");exit();}` write `if(headers_sent()){die('test: headers already sent');}else{die('test');}` to see if headers are already sent and if that code is ever reached at all. Probably some Error blocks your redirect. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php

Comment: If your server is running PHP 5.4 (or above) odds are your script is dying at `session_register` ... that function no longer exists. I'm guessing you're using a tutorial found online - I'd suggest finding a much, much newer one - this code looks archaic :|

Comment: @CD001   Yes, I garnered most of this through various tutorials and code samples and it probably is out of date. I'm still trying to learn php and don't quite understand it enough to write my own code from scratch. I'll try the update you've suggested.

Comment: @SalesAssistant And did you add the debugging code i posted? What'S the output there?

Comment: @AndreschSerj   It remains as a blank white page.

Comment: My server is set to PHP 5.2 by default with options to change to PHP 5.2 (FastCGI), PHP 5.4, and PHP 5.4 (FastCGI).

Answer (score 0):

You have javascript, css and html code in the same file which would be OK if you wrapped them in proper tags.

Try like this:

```
 <script>
 function login(showhide){
    if(showhide == "show"){
        document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
    }else if(showhide == "hide"){
        document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden"; 
    }
  }
</script>
<style> 
#popupbox{
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-right: 40%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 15%;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FBFBF0;
    border: solid #000000 2px;
    z-index: 9;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

There are several things that might go wrong in your code which I assume is from some tutorial and no way to check if it should work as it is but the redirection part header("Location: http://HOMEPAGE.com"); seems OK as long as the url you want to go is homepage.com

Comment: They're normally wrapped in the appropriate tags and the css is actually in an external page, but I just placed that all here as reference. The homepage index is the fall back redirect, but I can't seem to get it to go there after login.